# Can't ping hosts without sudo in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Day one with Ansible, and I'm following the getting started documentation.

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html

I created the '/etc/ansible/hosts' file with one host.

The command `sudo ansible all -m ping -vvvv` works fine.

When I drop the sudo I get:

```
02.my_first_host.com | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
    while connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

Is this a permissions issue with the /etc/ansible/hosts file?  I changed the ownership of /etc/ansible recursively to my user and no luck.

Comment: Can you directly ssh to the remote host w/o sudo? Do you have any special configuration in your `.ssh/config`? Do you use authentication via private key or password?

Comment: yes, private key to cPanel on CentOS system into root or any other user acct where i've added my key.  don't have a ~/.ssh/config file. only id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts

Comment: looking at output from -vvvv flag.  sudo is establishing connection for user: root whereas without sudo it's just trying my user.  I don't actually have a user on the server which matches the user on my mac.  

i tried 'ansible all -m ping -vvvv -u root' but got 'FAILED => SSH Error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host while connecting to'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the user in your inventory file through [behavioral parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters). But `-u`, like you did, should have the same result.

It might be Ansible is not using your private key because you don't have a .ssh/config. (wild guess!) You can explicitly pass the path to your key with `--private-key` or again set it as behavioral parameter in your inventory or group/host vars.

Via inventory:

```
[all:vars]
user=root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/file
```

Via group_vars, save as `group_vars/all` relative to your playbook:

```
...

user: root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /path/to/file

---
```

Comment: looks like that did it....thx!

`ansible all -m ping -vvvv --private-key .ssh/id_rsa -u root`

Comment: again this is ansible 101 for me, but i wanted to post in case it helps someone else.  i didn't have a ~/.ssh/config file so I added one with the following

`Host 01
    HostName 01.mydomain.com
    Port 22
    User root`

I then updated /etc/ansible with the host `01`.  I went back and was able to successfully ping without specifying the path to my private-key and without specifying the root user.

`ansible all -m ping` 

worked by itself.